# Update array while inside for loop over arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Numpy array and can successfully update all its elements with one line:

```py
array_1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
array_1 = array_1 / 10.0

print(array_1)
# [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4] -- Success!
```

However, when I have a list of Numpy arrays and iterate over them with a `for in` loop, I cannot apply the same operation and get back the desired results.

```py
array_1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
array_2 = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
array_3 = np.array([9, 10, 11, 12])

print(array_1) # [1 2 3 4]
print(array_2) # [5 6 7 8]
print(array_3) # [ 9 10 11 12]

for array in [array_1, array_2, array_3]:
    array = array / 10.0

print(array_1) # [1 2 3 4] -- No changes??
print(array_2) # [5 6 7 8]
print(array_3) # [ 9 10 11 12]
```

Why am I unable to update these arrays inside a loop? My understanding is that in the line

```py
for array in [array_1, array_2, array_3]:
```

`array` will be a pointer to each of the three Numpy arrays.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You have to distinguish "variable" from "value". In the first example you are creating a new value, and changing the binding of the variable `array_1` to the new value. In the second example, you are creating a new value, and changing the binding of `array` - but `array_1` still contains the old value.

Comment: Assigning to `array` makes it point to the new array, it doesn't update the array that it points to.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a shallow copy of the target array inside the for loop to edit the original.

```
for array in [array_1,array_2,array_3]:
    array[:] = array / 10.0
```

EDIT With Explanation---

In the for loop the control variable is its own object that deep copies the item being iterated over. We can use the [:] operation to make a shallow copy of the target item that references the original object. The following code demonstrates this concept:

```
array_1 = ['foo']
print(id(array_1)) # Original object id
for array in [array_1]:
    array = [1]
    print(id(array)) # Deep copy id
for array in [array_1]:
    array[:] = [1]
    print(id(array)) # Original object id
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? Why do we need to use `array[:] =` ?

Comment: Yeah no problem, should've been clearer @stackoverflowuser2010

Answer (score 1):

Becuse you're only assigning new values to the **control variable** of the loop, so you need to address the actual elements by **indexing**:

```
arrays = [array_1, array_2, array_3]

for i in range(len(arrays)):
    arrays[i] = arrays[i] / 10.0
```

or even more comprehensively:

```
arrays = [array / 10.0 for array in arrays]
```

or even by filtering:

```
arrays = list(filter(lambda x: x / 10.0, arrays))
```

## EDIT:

As `@ForceBru` noted in the comments section, in-place division would force the return of a `float` type array whereas the original is `int`.
So the following was changed in the first code snippet:
`arrays[i] /= 10.0 -> arrays[i] = arrays[i] / 10.0`

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I get this error: `TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'l') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''` pointing to the `arrays[i] /= 10.0` line. I'm using Python 3.7.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010, actually, I got the same error. Looks like the arrays are of integer type, but in-place division by a double (`10.0`) would require an array of type double, yet you can't write a double into an array of integers, hence the error. Division like `np.array([9, 10, 11, 12]) / 10.0` works fine because it creates a _new_ array.

Comment: @ForceBru: Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010, well, it didn't let you write a floating-point number into an array of integers - I guess that makes sense, since you didn't request any casting. However, NumPy 1.8 doesn't raise any errors in the same code and silently casts the resulting floats to integers. I think it's a feature that enforces better typing

Comment: @ForceBru: Hold on. Why does this work? `arrays[0] = arrays[0] / 10.0`. The LHS is an array of int, but the RHS is an array of double.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010, the LHS is actually "some Python object at `arrays[0]`" that's replaced with a new object created by the division. This is kind of "Python land", not "NumPy land", so NumPy types don't work here. Assigning to an array doesn't modify that array. Assigning to a slice like `array[0][:] = thing / 10.0` will attempt to modify it (write the values in the _new_ array returned by division into the original array).